# Convert a string to a datatype base on a string that contains datatype name

Tags: c#, string

I am converting a string to a datatype based on the another string that contains the name of datatype. 
I have two string like below:

```
string string_1 = "true";

string string_2 = "System.Boolean";
```

i need to convert the string 1 to the data type that is specified in string 2. how can i do that?(note that the string_2 can be each datatype)
must i use if's for checking string_2 with any type of datatype?

Comment: "note that the string_2 can be each datatype" - Do you mean it can be any type at all? Including ones which aren't in mscorlib? If the same type name occurs in multiple assemblies, would you have any indication of which one you want? How would you expect a string value to be converted to an arbitrary data type? (Convert.ChangeType is suitable for many "core" data types, but it won't be valid for *all* types...)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the target type is a primitive that is either `Convertible` or `Parse`able, you can try the following:

```
object result;
string string_1 = "true";
string string_2 = "System.Boolean";

var targetType = Type.GetType(string_2);

if (typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(targetType))
{
    result = Convert.ChangeType(string_1, targetType);
}
else
{
    var parseMethod = targetType.GetMethod("Parse", new[] {typeof (string)});

    if (parseMethod != null)
        result = parseMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { string_1 });
}
```

See [ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: the answer is very good but i have some other problem. in above code the type of result is shown as "object{bool}" but i need it to be "bool". how can i do that?

Comment: It is a `boolean`, but since in compile time the actual type is still unknown, you must refer to it as `object`. That's why you see `object{bool}`. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht, That would be the best of course. Yet, if you already know that you're dealing with a `bool`, why bother with dynamic conversion at all? If the only dynamic piece we're left with here is `string_1 = "true"` we can simply end up with `bool result = Boolean.Parse(string_1)`.

Comment: actually, i am reading the xml file. the xml file is written based on a dataset that contains several tables and each table some column and some rows. some of column contain different tyypes of data. for example one of columns contain bool data. the xml node of each cell has two one is the string of value of cell(string_1) and the other is the type of value(string_2).

Comment: i need to retrieve the dataset by reading the xml file. in the dataset each value must be the exact. for example the bool type data must be exactly bool for comparison purposes.(in other word in the original dataset that the xml file is written based on it when i write dataset.Tables[0]Rows[0][0]==true make the true result because the value on the cell is bool but if in reading i put object{bool} on that cell the result of the comment is false.)

Answer (score 1):

For the given type `ChangeType` works well:

```
Convert.ChangeType(string_1, Type.GetType(string_2))
```

But if you have different types, like an own class, this won't work. In that case, there is no such generic way, since the framework cannot now how to parse a value. If you try, you will get a `InvalidCastException`. In that case, you can only hand-write a converter.
In the special case, you have - beside primitives - only own classes, you could consider using a static-conversion method in each class for the job. Would probably look like this:

```
Type.GetType(string_2).GetMethod("convert").Invoke(string_1)
```

Anyway, no nice solution here. IMHO, the hand-written conversion (doing it with ifs) is the only proper way.

Comment: No need for those hacks on a custom type - you just have to implement `IConvertible` and `Convert.ChangeType` will work correctly.